# Почему объект Date возвращает миллисекунды?

Tags: javascript

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 2)
function getDateAgo(date, days){
 return date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
}


console.log(getDateAgo(date, 1))
```

Создайте функцию `getDateAgo(date, days)`, которая возвращает число, которое было `days` дней назад от `даты - date`.

Comment: [`setDate` возвращаемое значение](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Comment: @ Deonis можете объяснить я не понял ?

Comment: @xes вы возвращаете результат `setDate`, оно возвращает количество милисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года. Что не понятного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как указано в [описании](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> В результате выполнения функция setDate() **изменяет текущий объект** (Date) и **возвращает количество миллисекунд** от начала эпохи (1 января 1970 00:00:00 UTC) для полученного значения объекта.

В данном случае возвращается результат применения `.setDate`, следовательно вполне логично, что возвращается количество миллисекунд.

```js
var date = new Date(2015, 0, 2)

function getDateAgo(date, days) {
  return date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);
}

console.log('before:', date)
console.log(getDateAgo(date, 1))
console.log('after:', date)
```

Comment: тогда можно просто return (date.getDate() - days ?

Comment: @xes, нельзя - в данном коде синтаксическая ошибка.

Comment: а так будет правильно верно ? date.setDate(date.getDate() - days);                               return date.getDate()

Comment: @xes, а что ты хочешь вернуть-то?

Comment: просто в голове не могу уложить 1) date.setDate(date.getDate() - days); на мой взгляд должно вернуть мне дату, а не милисекунды

Comment: 2) return date.getDate() где берется из date.setDate(date.getDate() - days) получаю дату хотя если так будет ошибка date.getDate() - days

Comment: @xes, Ты так и не ответил на вопрос, что должна делать эта функция. Что конкретно ты хочешь вернуть? `getDate` - возвращает не дату, а день месяца указанной даты. Про ошибку вот тут `date.getDate() - days` вообще непонятно о чем ты.

Comment: возвращать день месяца

Comment: date.getDate() - days ?  ты сказал так нельзя вернуть дату месяца будет синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: @xes, синтаксическая ошибка будет в этом случае: `return (date.getDate() - days`

Comment: случайно скопировал вначале (